# Is there a better way than overriding every method of my parent Python class?

Tags: python

I have a Python parent class with dozens of methods. These parent methods return a parent object.

Each of these methods is similar to a math operation on two objects (e.g. add(self,other), multiply(self,other), which returns the result of the operation as a new object of the same class.

I also have a child class, and its objects use all the parent methods. However, I need them to return the result as a new object of the child class not the parent class.

The child class has additional member variables and it has additional methods.

My first thought is to override each parent method with a child method that a) calls the eponymous parent method (child's add calls super's add) , b) converts the returned parent object into a new child object to set the additional child member variable, and c) returns the new child object.

Apart from the additional property that the child has over the parent, the conversion also allows me to perform type assertions to ensure I have submitted a child object as a function parameter, where required.

Maybe this is all par for the course. But it seems tedious, and cluttery, as I will have to write many such small overriding methods that all do the same thing (call the parent's method verbatim, convert the result).

What I also do not like about this approach is that if the parent is from a library used elsewhere, I'd have to write the overrides for each parent method. To future proof I'd even have to do this for methods I presently don't intend to use.

What are my alternatives? Or is there a better way to set up the classes in the first place, to avoid this?

It has crossed my mind to switch parent and child, but then this new child (formerly parent) will carry around a member variable that means nothing to it, and will have access to methods that make no sense to it.

Comment: Have you verified than the non-overridden methods only return superclass type objects?  It seems like it should return objects of the same type as "self", which would be your subclass type.

Comment: @RufusVS good point. The parent.add has "return Parent(...)", so the Child.add will return a parent. Can this be done better?

Comment: If you have control of the Parent class code, write it as suggested in the answers others have given.  If you don't, you may have to do some tricky stuff with the `__getattribute__` magic method, to capture every method reference and modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the parent class' methods to take the class of `self` into consideration:

```
>>> class Parent:
...   def __init__(self): pass
...   def method(self): return self.__class__() # or type(self)()
...
>>> class Child(Parent): pass
...
>>> Child().method()
<__main__.Child object at 0x00000151EB7E0AF0>
>>> Parent().method()
<__main__.Parent object at 0x00000151EB977640>
```

Comment: yes this nicely takes care of the type issue. Is self.__class__() identical to type(self)() ? Also, I still have to deal with that missing member variable that the parent know nothing about. Any thoughts?

Comment: "have to deal with that missing member variable" - well, does its value depend on the logic for the operator? If so, then you have logic that's specific to the class anyway, and won't get away from an override. If not, well, you should be able to figure out appropriate constructor parameters that are the same for each class, and still let the child-specific constructor handle that member's value. I can't advise further without a new, more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have something like

```
class Parent:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Parent(...)
```

when you probably want

```
class Parent:
    def __add__(self, other):
        return type(self)(...)
```

This allows the method to return a value whose type depends on its *arguments* (specifically, its first argument) rather than which class defined it.

Comment: Neat! This could work, as it takes care of the type issue I have. And I own the parent class so it's feasible. The Child's __init__, called with type(self)(...), would have to take care of the missing member variable, perhaps as a default. Any further thoughts on this?

Comment: You'll need some kind of unvarying interface for creating the instance. A fixed signature for `__init__` would make it easy, though you could provide an additional class method (`return self._make_object(...)`) instead of having to use `__init__`. It's not necessarily a trivial problem to solve.